# Which NuGet package do I need for .NET Standard library with API controllers

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm upgrading a large application from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to ASP.NET Core 3.1.

We have assemblies that target .NET Standard 2.1, but I wonder which package I need to add to get access to `ControllerBase`, `HttpPostAttribute`, `IActionResult` and so on.

The package reference we previously used was *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc*, but there's no 3.1.0 version of that package (latest as of now is still 2.2.0).

Our host application (that consumes the above .NET Standard library) references *Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions* version 3.1.0, but that package can only be used in a *netcoreapp3.1* and not in a *netstandard2.1* library.

I'm confused and currently don't know which package I should use, so any help is more than welcome.

Comment: I think this article will help you: https://andrewlock.net/converting-a-netstandard-2-library-to-netcore-3/. It's actually part of a series, and they're all kind of awesome.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thank you, how did you find that so quickly? I've searched the web for hours...

Comment: I technically cheated . I follow that blog and saw the articles as he rolled them out. Wasn't that long ago, so still fresh in my memory.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Chris Pratt for linking [this article](https://andrewlock.net/converting-a-netstandard-2-library-to-netcore-3/) where it states that we now need to use:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Instead of individual Microsoft.AspNetCore.* package references.

So, I guess I'll have to live with the fact that libraries containing API controllers can no longer be shipped as `netstandard2.x` libraries.

Comment: It's technically not an issue. If you're dealing with ASP.NET Core stuff, you might as well just target .NET Core. It doesn't have application anywhere else where .NET Standard would be supported, particularly .NET Standard 2.1, which knocks off .NET Framework. If there's parts that are applicable to other targets like Unity or Xamarin, it would be best to break that out into a separate library where you can target maybe even .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: While moving forward, I think it's ugly. F.e. I have a library that sets up authentication (OpenID connect + cookie), and I now have to target netcoreapp3.1, have to add the FrameworkReference, so I can remove the no longer up-to-date `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies` BUT still have to add the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect`. This is nonsense. All I can think of now is: how will I explain this to my colleagues? Sorry for the rant :)